# How to retain the filtered (or different page) view of a datatable after editing in a Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am writing a Shiny app where I am rendering an editable datatable. In some instances I would like the user to filter the table or go to a different page and then make edits to the table. After this editing, I would like the current view of the table to remain while showing the edits in the table. The editing of a column also changes the values in another column, so both these edits need to be displayed while retaining the view.

This is the code I have come up with so far

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# create a sample data frame with 50 entries
df <- data.frame(
  name = paste0("Person ", 1:50),
  age = sample(20:60, 50, replace = TRUE),
  salary = sample(2000:5000, 50, replace = TRUE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# create a shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # create a reactiveValues object to store the data frame
  rv <- reactiveValues()
  rv$df <- df
  
  # render the table
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      rv$df,
      rownames = F,
      editable = T,
      filter = "top",
      selection = "none",
      extensions = c(
        "ColReorder",
        "Buttons"
      ),
      options = list(
        dom = "lBRrftpi",
        autoWidth = F,
        pageLength = 20,
        scrollX = F,
        ColReorder = T,
        buttons = list(list(extend = 'csv', filename= 'data'), 'print', 'copy')
      )
    )
  })
  
  # update the table when edited
  observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, {
    info <- input$table_cell_edit
    i <- info$row
    j <- info$col
    v <- info$value
    
    new_i <- i
    new_j <- j + 1
    new_val <- v * 100
    new_info <- data.frame(
      row = new_i,
      col = new_j,
      value = new_val
    )
    
    rv$df <<- editData(rv$df, info, rownames = F)
    
    if(j == 1){
      rv$df <<- editData(rv$df, new_info, rownames = F)
    }
    
    replaceData(proxy = dataTableProxy("table"), data = rv$df, resetPaging = FALSE)
  })
  
}

# run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

While the edits in the table and the dependant changes in the other column do work, the table view resets as soon as I edit a cell. Can someone please help me with code that retains the view after editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you observe is occuring because the data object you use is reactive and you update it, and then the table is re-rendered when the update occurs. The cool thing with a proxy is that you don't need a reactive data object. Also, you can pass the proxy object to `editData` and then there's no need of `replaceData`.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# create a sample data frame with 50 entries
df <- data.frame(
  name = paste0("Person ", 1:50),
  age = sample(20:60, 50, replace = TRUE),
  salary = sample(2000:5000, 50, replace = TRUE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# create a shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # render the table
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      df,
      rownames = F,
      editable = T,
      filter = "top",
      selection = "none",
      extensions = c(
        "ColReorder",
        "Buttons"
      ),
      options = list(
        dom = "lBRrftpi",
        autoWidth = F,
        pageLength = 20,
        scrollX = F,
        ColReorder = T,
        buttons = list(list(extend = 'csv', filename= 'data'), 'print', 'copy')
      )
    )
  })
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy("table")
  
  # update the table when edited
  observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, {
    info <- input$table_cell_edit
    i <- info$row
    j <- info$col
    v <- info$value
    
    new_i <- i
    new_j <- j + 1
    new_val <- v * 100
    new_info <- data.frame(
      row = new_i,
      col = new_j,
      value = new_val
    )
    
    df <<- editData(df, info, proxy, rownames = F)
    
    if(j == 1){
      df <<- editData(df, new_info, proxy, rownames = F)
    }
    
  })
  
}
```